# How does the Passport custom callback work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I don't understand this example

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

What I see happening here is

```
app.get('path', function(req, res, next) {/*bunch of code*/})(req, res, next)
```

How can this work since it is not a reference to a function that is placed behind (req, res, next) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your simplified example is a little off, probably due to mismatching brackets and such...

If I reduce the "official" passport example for custom callbacks, I get:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

So my first assumption is that `(req, res, next)` are being passed to a express-middleware-compliant function returned from `passport.authenticate`.

If I go poke around [the authenticate code on GitHub](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js), around line 81 or so (as of this writing) it looks like that's just what's happening starting with:

```
return function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    /* lots and lots of lines follow */
}
```

Comment: But the official custom callback example makes a point about having to invoke `req.login` manually when a custom callback is used.  I'm still not clear on why that is the case, because when I test it out no code in my `req.logIn` function gets executed.  I'd love to see a boilerplate with a working example of using the local strategy with a custom callback.